# Getting [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT when using gunicorn in the docker container

Tags: gunicorn, paddleocr

I get this weird error on some random request when accessing the server. I am using gunicorn, and exposing some ocr reading using paddleocr.

```bash
[2022-11-28 09:46:30 +0000] [7] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:1488)


--------------------------------------
C++ Traceback (most recent call last):
--------------------------------------
0   uv_run

----------------------
Error Message Summary:
----------------------
FatalError: `Process abort signal` is detected by the operating system.
  [TimeInfo: *** Aborted at 1669628790 (unix time) try "date -d @1669628790" if you are using GNU date ***]
  [SignalInfo: *** SIGABRT (@0x7) received by PID 1488 (TID 0x7f822beb9740) from PID 7 ***]
```

Do let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Exact same problem, with no trace. Image works on every other system, except prod ...